# Why didn't Kakashi take care of Naruto?

Tags: naruto

During the flashback some people have and or Kakashi, we find out that Namikaze Minato, Naruto's dad, was Kakashi's teacher, and that Kakashi had a big respect for him. Also, Uchiha Obito and Nohara Rin were his teammates. We also find out that in one of the flashbacks Kakashi has, it shows that when he was in the ANBU Minato buts him to guard and protect his wife, Kushina until she had about nine months of being pregnant. After Minato let Kakashi free for a couple of days, he went to visit Rin's grave and then Obito's engraved name to tell them that their sensei was having a child. I think a couple of days after that Naruto was born, and Kyuubi rampaged around the village. Minato risked his life to seal away Kyuubi inside Naruto to protect him and the village.

Minato and Kushina died and left Naruto all alone, so why didn't Kakashi take care of Naruto. I mean I know the Third gave Naruto money every month or so, but why didn't Kakashi at least watch Naruto from the shadows like he did with Kushina. Was it because he was too busy with his ANBU work, did he just forget his sensei had a child or was he too young to be taking care of kids. I mean he was just what 14 or something, he could have still managed to look at him or something. Or did he just feel it was wrong to get close to Naruto?

One of my cousins and me were talking about this a couple of days ago and it got me wondering. I didn't know how to respond to my cousin, so I just decided to ask you all.

Comment: Minato guarding Kushina is anime-only (a filler). It didn't happen in the manga.

Comment: he is still teenager when kyuubi attacked. . . .
and he is a famous Shinobi too, so Naruto will be seen as "weakness" by his enemy.

Comment: +1.  I thought about it myself long ago, when I had first watched Naruto. It's been around 5 years now. A nostalgic question to say the least. I hope someone can answer it with a good in-universe reason.

Comment: There was some Naruto filler, not the usual sludge but some legit story history of Kakashi's anbu days to jounin. I'm half sure you do see Kakashi watching Naruto from the shadows. And I think he was OK with Iruka for the most part + the Third's welfare.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Being Anbu and a guardian to Naruto doesn't seems like a great idea. And Naruto was in the care of the Third, so it might not seem necessary. It is also to be noted that, Kakashi has a hard time connecting to someone emotionally too. And as per his past, he wouldn't want to get attached to anyone and wanted to be only an Anbu. It was the Third who removed him from the Anbu and assigned him with various teams as tests, as shown in the anime filler, and in the end assigned with Team 7.

Answer (score 6):

As other people have said, he was doing his own thing. Also, when children are orphaned, they are cared for by the village in its entirety, so there is no need for one specific person to care for a child. Furthermore, the fact that he was close to Minato is a much bigger reason for him not to get close to Naruto, as they were keeping the fact that he was Minato's son a secret, probably for his own protection.

Comment: Oh yeah, I was wondering about that. Why did they not want people to find out Naruto was Minato's son? Was it because Minato was a skilled ninja and a lot of people wanted him dead?

Comment: Yeah, probably. Plus, Minato told Kakashi about the mysterious man that he had a run in with, and that he felt there was danger coming up in the future. So, that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 5):

Because everyone of the adult leaf village are terrible people. Both Kakashi and Hiruzen knew that Minato sacrificed himself and the future of his baby boy to protect the village and yet left Naruto to fend for himself both emotionally and materially.

In Shippunden Ep 480 Naruto meets Hiruzen for the FIRST TIME while gathering wild mushrooms and fishing to supplement his diet, he didn't have enough money to buy ramen. At the time Naruto seems to be about 5-6 and he didn't know what THE SUN was! There was obviously a serious lack of support and education up until then.

And Kakashi didn't do ANYTHING, as far as we can tell he just avoided Naruto like the plague. Sure he had no formal relationship with Naruto but you couldn't help out an orphan? Much less the orphan of your beloved student?!?!?

Naruto was being neglected by the entire village so obviously he needed someone to step in and help him out. That someone ended up being Iruka sensei, someone without any connection to Naruto.

If i was Minato's ghost I would be rolling in my grave if i knew how Kakashi and Hiruzen just left my orphaned child to suffer the abuse of the ignorant villagers, loneliness of having no family, and lack of financial support (the poor kid was hungry and had to scavenge for food) after I died to save the village.

The writers wanted to isolate Naruto and portray his growth by having him establish relationships with everyone so he couldn't have any support at the beginning. But the set up was just too unrealistic. Ninja welfare services would have been called years ago.